# Meaning of отлюбить мозг

Tags: значения

What is the meaning of отлюбить мозг? I'm guessing it is slang, correct?

Comment: It probably is, however, being Russian, I've never heard that one before.

Comment: As said many of the proposed answer, it masked the use of obscene language. It is intended to annoy or irritating, usually in communication.

Answer (score 11):

That's an euphemism for *отъебать мозг* which is one of the possible perfective forms of *ебать мозг* "to badger, to annoy with too much talking" (literally, "to fuck one's brain").

Answer (score 1):

It's a slang.
It means `to fuck a brain`.

Comment: Well, it's perfect form, so it would be 'to have/has fucked someone's brain'.

Comment: Please explain what this expression means. Your answer as  it is now is not very helpful in understanding this expression.

Comment: @Alex.S Please refer to this [answer](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/11633/3680) for much better explanation. As for me, unfortunately my English is not so good to explain better. I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

In this expression, "любить" is just an obvious euphemism to f-word. One say so, if she/he implies that she/he is going to swear. This euphemism is just as inappropriate as f-word, but it is less emotional.

It means having someone bored to death and blaming one for doing so.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian SE! Thank you very much for response. In future though tend to check whether  your answer is adding something new compared to answers already there.

Comment: This expression doesn't mean "bored to death" or similar. See the @Quassnoi's answer.

Comment: Sure, Alex. It does not mean that, if you translate as rude as original is.